# ARRAYFORMULA with AND in IF statement

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to combine an Arrayformula with a more complex if statement. I know there is a workaround but could not find a solution that is looking for a string in an if-statement as apposed to a number.

Here is what I'm trying to do:
Row A contains a number between 0 and 10
Row B contains three different strings: active, canceled, pending-cancel

Row C should give a "trial churned" where Row A is 1 and Row B is canceled.
Row C should give a "churned" where Row A is 2 and above and Row B is canceled.

Logic conclusion would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND((A1:A)=1; (B1:B)="canceled"); "trial churned"; IF((B1:B)="canceled"; "churned"); ""))
```

But since this is not how complex if statements work in Arrayformulas, I really don't know what to do now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AND() can't be iterated over an array. Instead, try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF( (A1:A = 1) * (B1:B= "canceled"); "trial churned"; IF(B1:B= "canceled"; "churned";)))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you so much! 

One little correction: The last If-Statement would need a third statement. Something like just empty "".